# Clicking Multiple Links In Selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm new to selenium ide and i want to automate some websites. i want it to be like this.

Click

```
Click Link 1
do some clicking inside that link
go back to the list of link
Click Link 2
do some clicking inside that link
go back to the list of link
Click Link 3
and so on
```

my only problem here is i don't know how it will click the first link from the top. this is the html of the website.

```
<h5>20 seconds ago</h5>
<ul>
<li class="notification-posted">
<img height="15" alt="" src="/assets/images/icons/notification-posted.png">
<a href="/account/54351-wews">wews</a>
send new
<a href="/news/53235">post</a> **Link 1**
</li>
</ul>
<h5>3 minutes ago</h5>
<ul>
<li class="notification-posted">
<img height="15" alt="" src="/assets/images/icons/notification-posted.png">
<a href="/account/632323-yokol">yokol</a>
submitted a new
<a href="/news/253129-loss">post</a> **Link 2**
</li>
</ul>
<h5>4 minutes ago</h5>
<ul>
<h3>6 minutes ago</h3>
<ul>
<h5>7 minutes ago</h5>
<ul>
<h2>8 minutes ago</h2>
<ul>
<li class="notification-posted">
<li class="notification-posted">
<li class="notification-posted">
<li class="notification-posted">
<li class="notification-posted">
<img height="15" alt="" src="/assets/images/icons/notification-posted.png">
<a href="/account/153316-problem">hey</a>
send new
<a href="/news/25151-helloworld">post</a> **link 3**
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Selenium ide, but I have used Selenium Webdriver for python which is similar

You just need to locate your element by **css selector**, specifically structural selectors; this is prob the easiest way if you have to dig through a lot of markup that doesn't have ids/classes

CSS has descendent selectors and psuedo-element selectors that allow you to target specific elements based solely on their position within the DOM, without needing an id or class

you can use the `:nth-of-type()` psuedo element, which targets the specific occurrence of that element based on the number you pass to it

for example in plain css:

a:nth-of-type(1)

would look within the body and select the a that is the first of its type. if you used 2 instead, it would target the second occurrence of an anchor.

for example, in selenium.webdriver this is how you'd find your element:

```
# ff is the webdriver.Firefox() instance

firstAnchor = ff.find_element_by_css_selector("a:nth-of-type(1)")

secondAnchor = ff.find_element_by_css_selector("a:nth-of-type(2)")
```

You can use that to target the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc  elements. There's also css attribute selectors too if you need to target an element based on a specific attribute value

```
ff.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/account/54351-wews']")
```

good luck mayne. cholla cholla hee haw

Comment: thank you for answering, that is for webdriver right? my problem is ide :(

Comment: if you have to use xpath for selenium ide, can you not specify the anchor like "//a[1]" or "//a[2]"? Like an array, it will find the nth occurrence of that element, which in your case is an anchor

Comment: that will work if the link was in the same /ul if that is the case the xpath would be like this

//div[@id='main']/ul[1]/li[1][@class='notification-posted']/a[2]
//div[@id='main']/ul[1]/li[2][@class='notification-posted']/a[2]

it can't click the link in other /ul , like this link.

//div[@id='main']/ul[2]/li[@class='notification-posted']/a[2]

anyway, if this is not possible in selenium ide , maybe i will just use the selenium webdriver i just don't know where to start LOL thank you so much chola chola he haw oh yea yea yea